# Ruby on Rails filling database with scraped data daily

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to setup a process which will scrape web data from a set of websites on a set schedule (maybe monthly, daily...etc). I want it to then fill the database tables. What would be the best way to do this? Would it be best to create a ruby script outside of rails, and then use a cron task on my own schedule to fill the database? Or is there a way I can do this within the rails framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1: Create a rake task**

ie: `lib/tasks/scrapping.rake`

```
namespace :scrapping do
  desc "Fetches new data from websites"
  task scrap_websites: :environment do
    # Call your scrapping classes/jobs/whatever code here
  end
end
```

**Step 2: Create a CRON task calling your rake task**

You can use a gem like **whenever** for this: https://github.com/javan/whenever

For instance, your `config/schedule.rb` could look like this:

```
every 1.day, at: '4:00am' do
  rake 'scrapping:scrap_websites'
end
```